# Returning a dictionary from a file

Tags: file, class, dictionary, python-3.4

I have have written this code defining a class

```
class OrderRecord:
"""Defines an OrderRecord class, suitable for use in keeping track of order records"""
    import tools2
    def __init__(self, string):
        """Creates a new OrderRecord object"""
        string = string.split(',')
        self.date = string[0]
        self.location = string[1]
        self.name = string[2]
        self.colour = string[3]
        self.order_num = string[4]
        self.cost = 0


    def cost_of_order(self):
        """Creates a list of the name and adds up the cost of each letter"""
        letter = list(self.name)
        for let in letter:
            self.cost = self.cost + self.tools2.letter_price(let, self.colour)
        return self.cost


    def __str__(self):
        """Calls the cost_of_order function and returns the split string in the required format"""
        self.cost = self.cost_of_order()
        return("Date:      {0}\nLocation:  {1}\nName:      {2}\nColour:    \
    {3}\nOrder Num: {4}\nCost:      {5:.2f}".format(self.date, self.location, \
    self.name, self.colour, self.order_num, self.cost))
```

Now I need to write a function that reads a file containing the following:

```
20130902,Te Rakipaewhenua,Vinas,parauri,8638
20130909,Te Papaioea,McClary,kikorangi,11643
20131215,Kapiti,Labrie,kikorangi,65291
20141106,Waihopai,Labrie,ma,57910
```

and returns a dictionary that has the location as the key and lists of OrderRecords as the values.

I know this isn't too hard of a task but I have been stuck on this for awhile because I can't get my head around what to do for it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please fix your code indentation. Which column in the file describes the location?

Comment: Sorry, it is the second column.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. It is not the solution but it has what you need with some modifications.

```
import collections    

dct_result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for line in open('file_path'):
    fields = line.split(',')
    # index 1 being the second column
    dct_result[field(1)].append(OrderRecord( some args ))
```